# How to detect what causes "half-dead" Seagate internal HDD?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, hardware-failure

I had been using a **Seagate Barracuda ST1000DM003 1TB HDD** for nearly 10 years now. But now it is "half-dead". I had windows 10 on it. It all started one day my PC did not boot up. I thought that it was a Windows problem and restored it to the latest restore point but it didn't work.

After several days I tried to boot up my PC again and it booted but it was **so slow**. I couldn't access all my files. And when I tried to open some folders there was an endless loading.

Today I bought a new HDD and installed Win10 on it. And connected failed HDD with an additional SATA port. The problem is. Sometimes my pc opens it and sometimes **don't**. I tried booting and shutting down several times. I've managed to rescue some folders from it.

When it opens I can see all my folders and file. No data is lost.

When I connect this HDD to my Linux devide it is listed on **lsblk**. I tried to use **ddrescue** with my other Linux pc. When I run the ddrescue it runs to a certain point. And from that point, it starts to see all blocks as **errored**. But I know that this is something about time because ddrescue always starts to fail after 7-8 minutes. Until then everything is good.

When I start the ddrescue I set the **-i parameter** to whatever position and I get successful results untill certain time. Then it starts to fail again. Even sometimes it does fail at start. Note that - although it is not advised - I tried to mount this HDD on linux. And it gave the message "can't read superblock".

Finally my question is: How can I diagnose what is the problem with this HDD? Is it caused by corrupted content or is it a PCB fail or is it likely that heads are damaged?

I want to diagnose to restore my hard drive.

Even now, when I connect it sometimes windows sees it as a disk, and sometimes don't.

I don't think that this is a physical damage problem. Because it starts to run as soon as I turn my pc on.

Comment: You should try recover the data an forget about restoring this to a usable state. Look into HDDSuperClone. If you don't want to baby sit the recovery and power cycle the drive when it starts returning errors it can be coupled with a relay to automate power cycling.

Comment: To get an idea, SMART may be of help. Just observe values do not run short/extended test. Each time you access the drive, it's one step closer to death. Make everything you do count. Cloning is less stressful than copying individual files.

Comment: By your description it does sound like an issue with the drive itself. 10 years is a long lifespan for a spinning disk. Whichever way, before doing anything else with it I'd get another TB drive, hook both up to a computer and try to get all data transferred to the new drive.

Answer (score 2):

**Be warned that DIY data recovery comes with risks**. *Any* data recovery comes with risks as each time you access the drive you push it closer towards the edge. A data recovery specialist's tools and procedures are designed to reduce risk and a specialist would be your best option if the data is of value.

> I want to diagnose to restore my hard drive.

Run a SMART tool and observe only, do not run short or extended tests. Forget about restoring the drive to a usable state, concentrate on recovering data. If the data is of no value, save yourself the trouble and frustration and bin the drive.

The drive exhibits all sings of a rapidly degrading drive. In general such a drive is best handled by cloning/imaging tools designed for the purpose. HDDSuperClone (free / open source) is such a tool. Using file recovery tools on a degraded drive is asking for trouble.

Symptoms as you describe can be automatically handled by HDDSuperClone although automated power-cycles (in case drive starts reporting only errors for example) require additional hardware.

**So first step is cloning / imaging the drive**. Once you have the image file / clone, put the patient drive aside and work with the disk image.

Use file recovery software only on the clone / disk image! Depending on amount of data that could not be salvaged from the patient, filesystem reconstruction  may or may not be possible.

> Is it caused by corrupted content or is it a PCB fail or is it likely
> that heads are damaged?

Degrading media and perhaps heads. 95% certain this is not a PCB issue. The more you use the drive, the worse it will get. At some point the drive will fail. A head will fail or the amount of errors will start for example overflow the g-list, overwriting other firmware modules in the process.

In cases like this, some labs will check the drive in a cleanroom by default, others will try imaging it first. To image 'quirky heads' can be disabled individually, this way data least at risk can be copied first.

Always the idea is, get the easy data first before starting with the bits that will most likely increase stress on the drive and risk of failing.